# Unable to mock the react useLocation hook with jest for shallow mounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test a component that is using the useLocation react hook, but even though I mocked it, useLocation().pathname results in an error, as useLocation is undefined.

Another question I have is if I successfully mock useLocation() in this test file, will it also work for the rest? Is there a way to mock modules only for a single jest test file?

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    pathname: '/route'
  })
}));

describe('ComponentUsingLocation', () => {
  test('should render', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <ComponentUsingLocation />
    );

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: shallow will not render a hook

Comment: Is there any way to access useLocation().pathname in a shallow mounted component?

Comment: nope, try mount or https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/

Comment: Thank you! I also understand it might be possible to use jest.spyOn()

Comment: jest-react-hooks-shallow did help, and not using jest.fn().mockImplementation, and replacing it with a regular function did the trick, still, any idea if this mock will work in the file it is defined in, or all of them?

Comment: Don't. Don't partially mock things, especially ones you don't own. Render the component in a memory router, so you can test the actual behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, so I should do something like this wrapper = shallow(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/foo"]} initialIndex={1}><ComponentUsingLocation /></MemoryRouter>) and then expect(wrapper.find('ComponentUsingLocation').dive()).toMatchSnapshot(). The problem is that useLocation is still undefined.

Comment: Were you still mocking out `react-router-dom` at that point? (Also FWIW toMatchSnapshot is just change detection, not testing.)

Comment: I wasn't still mocking useLocation, or anything else. I'll try again and see if I can figure out what the problem is. Regarding the matching snapshot, I know, it's just an example, it helps me see what is actually being tested.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom") as {},
  useLocation: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        pathname: "/route",
        search: '',
        hash: '',
        state: null
      };
  })
}));
```

and to answer your second question, if you want it to work in all the test cases inside a file, you can mock it on `beforeAll()` jest function.

more info - https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown

Comment: This did not work, but I found something that does: jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useLocation: () => ({
    pathname: 'localhost:3000/example/path'
  })
}));

Answer (score 0):

It seems a different implementation does work, for some reason not using jest.fn().mockReturnValue and simply using a regular function instead does the job.

I also have the jest-react-hooks-shallow package installed in a standard react-scripts project.

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useLocation: () => ({
    pathname: 'localhost:3000/example/path'
  })
}));
```